# Complex matrix multiplication with tensorflow-backend of Keras

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, keras, matrix-multiplication

Let matrix `F1` has a shape of `(a * h * w * m)`, matrix `F2` has a shape of `(a * h * w * n)`, and matrix `G` has a shape of `(a * m * n)`.

I want to implement the following formula which calculates each factor of `G` from factors of `F1` and `F2`, using tensorflow backend of Keras. However I am confused by various backend functions, especially `K.dot()` and `K.batch_dot()`.

$$ G_{k, i, j} = \sum^h_{s=1} \sum^w_{t=1} \dfrac{F^1_{k, s, t, i} * F^2_{k, s, t, j}}{h * w} $$ i.e.:

[image]

(Image obtained by copying the above equation within $$ and pasting it to [this site](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php))

Is there any way to implement the above formula? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Tensorflow [`tf.einsum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) (which you could wrap in a `Lambda` layer for Keras):

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a, h, w, m, n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

F1 = tf.random_uniform(shape=(a, h, w, m))
F2 = tf.random_uniform(shape=(a, h, w, n))

G = tf.einsum('ahwm,ahwn->amn', F1, F2) / (h * w)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    f1, f2, g = sess.run([F1, F2, G])

    # Manually computing G to check our operation, reproducing naively your equation:
    g_check = np.zeros(shape=(a, m, n))
    for k in range(a):
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                for s in range(h):
                    for t in range(w):
                        g_check[k, i, j] += f1[k,s,t,i] * f2[k,s,t,j] / (h * w)

    # Checking for equality:
    print(np.allclose(g, g_check))
    # > True
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!